# Placing multiple ImageButtons in List View in Android Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, imagebutton

I am new to Android and working on an app that needs to make use of a ListView such that each row of the list view has 3 clickable images. There could be several rows but each row must have 3 ImageButtons. Each ImageButton will have an onClick event which will be used to determine which image was selected by the user. The image below depicts what I need:

[image: Picture showing two rows with 3 images each.]

I am creating the ListView and the ImageButtons on-the-fly and adding them to my activity's layout. I have named all images like bigavatar1, bigavatar2, bigavatar3 (42 in total) and so no, to be able to use them in a loop.

In the OnCreate function of my activity, this is what I have been able to come up with so far:

LinearLayout mainScreen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainAvatarScreen);
            mainScreen.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

```
        String PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

        int[] imgId = new int[42];
        String fnm = "bigavatar"; //  this is image file name

        ListView avatarListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.membersListView);

        for(int i=0; i<42; i++)     {
        imgId[i] = getResources().getIdentifier(PACKAGE_NAME+":drawable/"+fnm+(i+1) , null, null);

        //ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
        ImageButton img = new ImageButton(this);  //create new ImageButton
        //Set ImageButton's Properti es
        img.setMaxHeight(64);
        img.setMaxWidth(64);
                 img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imgId[i])); //src
        img.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_imagebutton_selector));

        mainScreen.addView(img);
    }
```

Obviously, the above code is incomplete and is able to only create the images but not make use of the ListView yet.

I need help at this stage. How should I:

- Add the ImageButtons to the ListView
- Would it be a good idea to create a LinearLayout for each row, set it's orientation to Horizontal to organize my buttons neatly within each row?
- Will I have to create a custom adapter for the ListView? I have tried adding Strings from an ArrayList but the requirement here is to add a set of 3 ImageButtons to each row of the ListView.
- I need an onClick event on each ImageButton that will return be the name/id of the button clicked. This will not create a conflict with the ListView and will work as intended?

It would be great if someone can help me with the code and the strategy here. I am not very experienced so pardon me if I am using or suggesting incorrect designing strategies, I want to learn and get this activity ready asap. Please do explain your answers. Thanks :)

Comment: shouldn't that be a gridview instead ?

Comment: You can probably do this with a `GridView` and a `SimpleAdapter`, so you won't have to subclass an adapter. GridView will save you a lot of time arranging all your data into groups of three.

Comment: Ohh I had no idea that something like GridView existed! Can you please help me with the code and working of the GridView? I will really appreciate the help :)